# Graph concatenation/group on Altair

Tags: python, altair

I've been looking for the documentation to simplify my code, and group in fewer lines my graphs on Altair. I'm creating individually each plot and grouping them through concatenation.

Do you guys have any recommendations? I insist, to simplify the code.

Here's my code:

```
#Lugares de ocio
retail_recretation = alt.Chart(sub_df).mark_line(color="green", size=1).encode(
    alt.X('date:T', title = " "),
    alt.Y('retail_and_recreation_percent_change_from_baseline:Q', title='Cambio porcentual'),
).properties(
    title = "Lugares de ocio",
    width = 300,
)

#Mercados y farmacias
grocery_pharmacy = alt.Chart(sub_df).mark_line(color="green", size=1).encode(
    alt.X('date:T', title = " "),
    alt.Y('grocery_and_pharmacy_percent_change_from_baseline:Q',  title='Cambio porcentual'),
).properties(
    title = "Mercados y farmacias",
    width = 300
)

#Parques y playas 
parks = alt.Chart(sub_df).mark_line(color="green", size=1).encode(
    alt.X('date:T', title = " "),
    alt.Y('parks_percent_change_from_baseline:Q', title='Cambio porcentual')
).properties(
    title = "Parques y playas",
    width = 300
)

#Transporte público
transit = alt.Chart(sub_df).mark_line(color="green", size=1).encode(
    alt.X('date:T', title = " "),
    alt.Y('transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline:Q', title='Cambio porcentual')
).properties(
    title = "Transporte público",
    width = 300
)

#Lugares de trabajo
workplaces = alt.Chart(sub_df).mark_line(color="green", size=1).encode(
    alt.X('date:T', title = " "),
    alt.Y('workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline:Q', title='Cambio porcentual')
).properties(
    title = "Lugares de trabajo",
    width = 300
)

#Residenciales
residential = alt.Chart(sub_df).mark_line(color="green", size=1).encode(
    alt.X('date:T', title = " "),
    alt.Y('residential_percent_change_from_baseline:Q', title='Cambio porcentual')
).properties(
    title = "Residenciales",
    width = 300
)

#Concat
par1 = retail_recretation | grocery_pharmacy | parks
par2 = transit | workplaces | residential

#Concat2
mobility_colima = par1 & par2
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [fold transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/fold.html) and then make a facet encoding.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

rand = np.random.RandomState(0)
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='D', periods=30),
    'A': rand.randn(30).cumsum(),
    'B': rand.randn(30).cumsum(),
    'C': rand.randn(30).cumsum(),
    'D': rand.randn(30).cumsum(),
})

alt.Chart(data).transform_fold(
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
).mark_line().encode(
    x='date:T',
    y='value:Q',
    facet=alt.Facet('key:N', columns=2)
)
```

[image]